# Install kernel 5.11.0 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, downgrade

I am developing a software that use a driver that require Linux kernel 5.11.0 at most.

Currently I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15.0-48.54-generic.

Can I install Linux kernel 5.11.0?
I have install mainline and --list command returns:

```
$ mainline --list-installed
mainline 1.0.16
Distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Architecture: amd64
Running kernel: 5.15.0-48-generic
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Found installed: 5.15.0-47.51
Found installed: 5.15.0-48.54
Found installed: 5.15.0.48.48
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04?

Comment: Sorry I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I'm going to edit the my question.

Comment: You could consider installing Ubuntu 20.04 in a virtual machine (i.e., `VirtualBox`)...

Comment: So you're developing a software, that requires an older kernel. Are you expecting that people running your software should downgrade the kernel as well? If yes, you should probably consider other options.